# Searching json for a specific value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm attempting use Python 3 to search through json for specific variables. The results usually look something like this.

```
[
  {
    "string": "00002000",
    "existedPrior": true
  },
  {
    "string": "00002001",
    "existedPrior": false
  },
  {
    "string": "00002002",
    "existedPrior": true
  },
  {
    "string": "00002003",
    "existedPrior": true
  },
  {
    "string": "00002004",
    "existedPrior": false
  }
]
```

The goal of this script would be to search these values for where "existedPrior" is false, then take the string from that value and insert it into an array. I could then later take the values of the array and re-query them against another endpoint for more data.

From what I've gathered, this is kind of close to what I'm hoping to do, but isn't actually getting me there.

```
import json
import requests

q = 'https://website.com/api/var'
r = requests.get(url=q)

strings = []

data = r.json()
i = 0

for item in data:
    if item['existedPrior'] == 'false':
        i += 1
        strings.append(item['string'])
        print(item['string'])
    else:
        break

print("New additions: ", i)
```

It's my understanding that json and python don't share the same "definition" of boolean, and this causes trouble. I read elsewhere on stackoverflow on how to handle this, but it involved json.dumps and json.loads and all sorts of messy bits that I wasn't 100% sure were needed.

As an aside, would it be better to just convert the json into a python dictionary and search from there?

Comment: Bools are converted to python data types fine. `r.json()` is already deserializing the json into a python dictionary.

Comment: As a side note, do you really need that `i`? It's going to be the same as `len(strings)` (unless you've got a bug—in which case it will always be `i`, not `len(strings)`, that's wrong).

Comment: What may be confusing is that JSON spells its `false` value differently from how Python spells its `False` literal. (And likewise for `true`/`True` and `null`/`None`.) That's why you can't just `eval` (or `ast.literal_eval`) a JSON text as a Python literal. But JSON doesn't have any definition of what its `false` means (it's just defined as one of three literal values, with no interpretation given for any of them), so its definition can't be any different from Python's.

Comment: Also, you may have heard that JavaScript's definition of falseness is different from Python's. That one _is_ true (e.g., in JavaScript, `NaN` is false), it's just not relevant here.

Comment: Thank you @jordanm, I'm looking into how to properly utilize dictionaries now then.

Comment: @abarnert the `i` isn't needed, you're right. I'm somewhat new to python and that's just something left over from other languages. I could just use `.length`.

Also, thank you for clarification on json/python.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using enumerate:

```
for index, value in enumerate(data):
    if value["existedPrior"] == False:
        string.append(data[index]['string'])
```